# Finding back-to-back dates using Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, filter

I have an NBA Dataset that looks like:

| Player | Game_date |
| --- | --- |
| Lebron James | 2023-10-11 |
| Lebron James | 2023-10-12 |
| Lebron James | 2023-10-18 |
| Kobe Bryant | 2023-11-02 |
| Kobe Bryant | 2023-11-03 |
| Kobe Bryant | 2023-11-09 |

And I want to filter it so it only includes back-to-back games so that it would look like this:

| Player | Game_date |
| --- | --- |
| Lebron James | 2023-10-11 |
| Lebron James | 2023-10-12 |
| Kobe Bryant | 2023-11-02 |
| Kobe Bryant | 2023-11-03 |

Please consider this only a snippet of my entire dataset so I would need to hopefully find a way to filter the entire dataset versus just this small little snippet.

If you want to create the data frame:

```
data = [
{'Player': 'Lebron James', 'Game_date': '2023-10-11'},
{'Player': 'Lebron James', 'Game_date': '2023-10-12'},
{'Player': 'Lebron James', 'Game_date': '2023-10-18'},
{'Player': 'Kobe Bryant', 'Game_date': '2023-11-02'},
{'Player': 'Kobe Bryant', 'Game_date': '2023-11-03'},
{'Player': 'Kobe Bryant', 'Game_date': '2023-11-09'},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I tried doing this:

```
# Convert 'game_date' column to datetime format
df['game_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['game_date']).dt.date

# Sort DataFrame by player_id and game_date
df.sort_values(by=['player_name', 'game_date'], inplace=True)

# Calculate the difference between consecutive game dates and store the result in 'b2b' column
df['b2b'] = df.groupby('player_name')['game_date'].apply(lambda x:x.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0))).dt.days
```

Comment: Do you want to find **two or more** consecutive games?  Or just two exactly?

Comment: Since it’s the NBA there will only ever be two consecutive games. So two exactly !

Comment: Ensure the game records are sorted first by player and then by date. Then iterate over the game records. If the current game record has the same player as the next game record, and the game dates differ by one day, then you have found back-to-back games. What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to check if days are successive, then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the mask backwards by one step to include the starting row, finally perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# ensure datetime (NOT date!)
df['Game_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Game_date'])

# identify rows to keep
keep = (df.groupby('Player')['Game_date']
          .transform(lambda g: (m:=g.diff().dt.days.eq(1)) | m.shift(-1))
       )

# select
out = df.loc[keep]
```

Output:

```
         Player  Game_date
0  Lebron James 2023-10-11
1  Lebron James 2023-10-12
3   Kobe Bryant 2023-11-02
4   Kobe Bryant 2023-11-03
```

Intermediates (with two extra dates to demonstrate multiple back-to-back per player):

```
         Player  Game_date    diff      m m.shift(-1)  m|m.shift(-1)
0  Lebron James 2023-10-11     NaT  False        True           True
1  Lebron James 2023-10-12  1 days   True       False           True
2  Lebron James 2023-10-18  6 days  False         NaN          False
3   Kobe Bryant 2023-11-02     NaT  False        True           True
4   Kobe Bryant 2023-11-03  1 days   True       False           True
5   Kobe Bryant 2023-11-09  6 days  False       False          False
6   Kobe Bryant 2023-12-11 32 days  False        True           True
7   Kobe Bryant 2023-12-12  1 days   True         NaN           True
```